# react native how to import and use pure android sdk in react native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pos, react-native-native-module, native-module

I wanted to print  receipt from react native app my problem is the device is smart pos
so i have this documentation it is explain how to user their SDK in pure android project

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ECps1NEr279hfqdp-8boVxIsqaSkFBJ/view?usp=sharing

what i need is how to import this SDK into my react native project and us it

i try to add the file into android main folder but it did not work

Comment: after 1 year, do you have any solution? tks u.